# How to find the name of a row that has the highest value in a column

Tags: r, dataframe

i am trying to find the name of the row which shows the highest value of a singular column in my data frame, I have tried using

`rownames(which.max(df[,1]))`
and

`rownames(df)[apply(df,1,which.ax)]`

however the first piece of code only gives me the word 'NULL' and the second piece of code provides me a long list of many row names.

using `which.max(df[,1])` provides me with the correct number, but not the corresponding name of the row i am looking for.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may do

```
 rownames(df)[which.max(df[[1]])]
```

If we want for each column

```
sapply(df, \(x) row.names(df)[which.max(x)])
```

Comment: thank you very much - exactly what i was looking for :) would you be able to explain what [1] is telling R to do?

Comment: @jumpsuitgallion it is just that you are extracting the first column with `[[1]]`

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `max.col` by first transposing the dataframe like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(V1 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 row.names = c(1,2,3,4,5))
df
#>   V1
#> 1  1
#> 2  2
#> 3  3
#> 4  4
#> 5  5
rownames(df)[max.col(t(df))]
#> [1] "5"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>